# Manipulating table cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{1: "Manchester", 2: "London", 3: "Bristol", 4: "Birmingham", 5: "Liverpool", 6: "Newcastle", 7: "York", 8: "Edinburgh", 9: "Glasgow", 10: "Aberdeen"}
```

I am using this object to create a select list in the cell of a table in a column called "city". When this value changes I want to update the value of another cell in a column called "id" with the key from the object (which equates to the id).

Is there a way in which I can bind the change in one cell with the other. I'm struggling to figure it out.

One thing I should mention is that this is a basic use case, in reality the values and keys could be anything so I need a dynamic way to select the corresponding column to update when the value in the select field is changed.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

I am using a data-grid component called Ag-Grid to generate the table and then I am creating my select field like this:

```
function customEditor(params) {
    let editing = false;
    let setSelectionOptions = TableStore.getTable().lookups[0].map;

    let eCell = document.createElement('span');
    let eLabel = document.createTextNode(params.value);
    eCell.appendChild(eLabel);

    let eSelect = document.createElement('select');

    Object.keys(setSelectionOptions).forEach(key => {
        let eOption = document.createElement('option');
        eOption.setAttribute('value', setSelectionOptions[key]);
        eOption.innerHTML = setSelectionOptions[key];
        eSelect.appendChild(eOption);
    }); 
    eSelect.value = params.value;

    eCell.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!editing) {
            eCell.removeChild(eLabel);
            eCell.appendChild(eSelect);
            eSelect.focus();
            editing = true;
        }
    });

    eSelect.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        if (editing) {
            editing = false;
            eCell.removeChild(eSelect);
            eCell.appendChild(eLabel);
        }
    });

    eSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (editing) {
            editing = false;
            let newValue = eSelect.value;
            params.data[params.colDef.field] = newValue;
            eLabel.nodeValue = newValue;
            eCell.removeChild(eSelect);
            eCell.appendChild(eLabel);
        }
    });

    return eCell;
}
```

where params is provided by the grid functionality and in this case is used to set the new value to go into the cell, and `setSelectionOptions` is the object I previously mentioned. What I now need to do is select the other relevant column and change the value in there to the correct corresponding value.

Comment: Of course there's a way of doing it, but to help you do that we'd need to see your ("*[MCVE]*" code, both the HTML and attempted JavaScript) to see where you're going wrong, and you would need to explain the faults in your current, or attempted, implementation.

Comment: Argh sorry posted the question too early, got caught up in something else and wasn't really paying attention to what I was posted! Anyway I updated the question.